# Garbage characters are printed on mouse scrolling on iTerm2

Tags: scrolling, iterm2

Sometimes whenever I use my mouse to scroll on iTerm2 the scrolling does not work, instead printing a lot of garbage characters on the screen.

[image]

This happens very inconsistently. Sometimes it happens abruptly, and sometimes it doesn't happen for months. At first I thought it is just a bug, but it even happens just after I restart my machine, and also I could not find other people experience this problem that much on the web. So maybe something is wrong with my environment...

This does not happen on Mac's default Terminal and happens on various Macs I have. Also, quitting and launching the app again does not solve the problem.

What is the potential reason of this behavior and how can I fix it? I use Big Sur 11.0.1 but it happened on other macOS in the past. iTerm2 is 3.4.3.

Comment: this can happen in windows power shell too - couldn't find another way than close the window and start a new one ...

Answer (score 8):

This was driving me bananas as well. I noticed that it only seemed to happen in a shell - which led me to install the iTerm2 shell integration, and after a restart of the shell, viola! No more garbage on click and scroll!

Either click **iTerm2 -> Install Shell Integration** in the top menu, or run the command manually:

`curl -L https://iterm2.com/shell_integration/install_shell_integration.sh | bash`

ref [iTerm2 Shell Integration](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Mouse Reporting** mode might be ON.

Turn it off by:

- Right click on the terminal
- Choose `Terminal State`
- Turn off `Mouse Reporting`

Mouse Reporting should be unchecked.

[image]

#### Update

As mentioned in the comment of this answer, you can disable Visual Mode by holding down the `Option` key while you are selecting the text.

**Enable mouse reporting**

If selected, applications may choose to receive information about the mouse. This can be temporarily disabled by holding down Option.

[https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-terminal.html#:~:text=Enable%20mouse%20reporting](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-terminal.html#:%7E:text=Enable%20mouse%20reporting)

Comment: If you want disable temporarily you can hold down "Option" while scrolling (Ref: https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-terminal.html#:~:text=Enable%20mouse%20reporting)

Comment: Thank you this worked